# Change background color HTML Area coordinates

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have an image of a china cabinet.

Using an image map I can plot the points and make the hrefs:

```
<area id="vasetop" alt="" title="Vase on Top" href="#" onClick="reply_click(this)" shape="rect" coords="276,27,379,96" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  />
```

I have database with all the item names and each one has a value of 0 if its available and 1 if it is not available.

What I would like to do is if say:

vasetop has a value of 1 I would like to remove it somehow.

My code would look something like

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stuff where status='1'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['items'] == "vasetop"){
            <area show black box at these coords="276,27,379,96" />
        }
        else {
            <area id="vasetop" alt="" title="Vase on Top" href="#" onClick="reply_click(this)" shape="rect" coords="276,27,379,96" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  />
        }
}
```

Something close to that.

Is there anyway to can set the background color of coords in html?

What i realy want is some code that would do the following.

```
<div coords="276,27,379,96" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may place absolutely positioned div on top of your map, something like:

```
<div style="position:absolute; 
top:27px; 
left:276px; 
width:103px; /*379-276*/
height:69px; /* 96-27 */
background:#fff;"></div>
```

But it is easy with rectangular shape only, doing such thing with circle and polygon is a lot trickier...